# TypeError at /admin/auth/user/

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I get such an error when I try to delete a user from admin panel

> TypeError at /admin/auth/user/
>   'bool' object is not callable

models.py

```
class PROFILE(models.Model):
kullanıcı = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=True)
birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name="Birthday",
                            blank=False,null=False)
gender   = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False,null=
                            False,choices=gender)
language = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False,null=False,
                            verbose_name="language",choices=languages)


def set_token(self):

    self.token = ''.join([choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') 
                                for i in range(15)])

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PROFILE, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.set_token()

class Meta:

    verbose_name_plural = 'PROFILE'
    ordering= ["id"]

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.kullanıcı.username)



class Q(models.Model):
   author  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ... class Meta, __str__ ....
```

Firstly 'kullanıcı' was 'user' but I changed because of the possibility of conflict django. But still I have a this problem

> TypeError at /admin/auth/user/
>   'bool' object is not callable
>   Request Method:     POST
>   Request URL:    http://192.168.1.34:8000/admin/auth/user/
>   Django Version:     2.1
>   Exception Type:     TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'bool' object is not callable
>   Exception Location:     /home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py in collect, line 221
>   Python Executable:  /home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/bin/python
>   Python Version:     3.6.5
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/ask',
>    '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
>    '/usr/lib/python3.6',
>    '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>    '/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Cum, 31 Ağu 2018 16:35:51 +0000

>

> Traceback:
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
>     607.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>     44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
>     223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
>     45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
>     1711.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
>     1411.             response = func(self, request, queryset)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py" in delete_selected
>     28.     deletable_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected = modeladmin.get_deleted_objects(queryset, request)>
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_deleted_objects
>     1833.         return get_deleted_objects(objs, request, self.admin_site)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in get_deleted_objects
>     134.     collector.collect(objs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in collect
>     197.             return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/mete/Masaüstü/ask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in collect
>     221.                         field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/
>   Exception Value: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: The stack trace of the error might be helpful. Can you add that?

Comment: did you run migrate the column name change  in the database?

Comment: @mete eroğlu Did you extended the `User` mode? Did you anything added to the `admin.py`?

Comment: @SachinKukreja yes I tried one more there is no error in migrate

Comment: @JPG I cant understand first question. I tried as admin. Also I saved my models in django.site.register(model)

Comment: Can you add the `admin.py` file?

Comment: Yes I have Also I solved and you solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your **`on_delete`** argument of **`Profile`** model.
The **`on_delete`** argument **should not** be a ***boolean*** value. The possible values for **`on_delete`** can found here, [Related Field- `on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).
So, Change your **`PROFILE`** as,

```
class PROFILE(models.Model):
    kullanıcı = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .... other fields
```

Comment: Thanks for everything. Actually how it can be. I thought it was true 'on_delete=True' I learned wrong

Comment: You could read more about that in the link I attached in answer,

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually I used true value in second model. But I thought they were the same. I have to be more careful. Again thanks